# Having problems with simple fields saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, simple-form

I have problem with form, simple fields don't saving in array options

Product.rb

```
   class Product
      include Mongoid::Document
      field :name, type: String
      field :options, type: Array 
      field :active, type: Boolean
      field :main, type: Boolean
      field :category, type: String
    end
```

_form.html.haml

```
= simple_form_for [:admin, @product] do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  .form-inputs
    = f.input :name
    = f.input :main
    = f.input :category
    = f.input :active
    = f.simple_fields_for :options do |ff|
      = ff.input :mass
      = ff.input :volume
      = ff.input :price
      = ff.input :amount
      = ff.input :packing
  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit
```

product_controller.rb

```
    def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to [:admin, @product], notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
    def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:name, :active, :main, :category, :options )
    end
```

Product name is saved, but options is nill.
@product[:options]` is nil

The problem is that I have a lot of that is already working on the basis of seeds. In seeds options listed as an array, not a class. For this it is necessary to find a way out without using the class option.

Comment: could you post the error? You should probably define some admin_params as a allowed params

Comment: Do you mean they don't save if you click the "submit" button? Why don't you show your "save" method in the `product_controller.rb` which would be quite relevant in this case? And how/where is `@product` defined?

Comment: Oh by the way, your `options` field should be a Hash not an array. Or you have no way to differentiate between values and keys. Also, can you post your

Comment: ...can you copy paste the parameters list that appears on the console when you POST ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Object Type

`:options` is not a simple field here. Either you want it to be a nested hash of key/value pairs,

```
options = {
  'mass' => '45kg',
  'volume' => '35L'
}
```

or if you want to keep the array structure, it should be an array of array like

```
options = [ ['mass', '35kg'], ['volume', '35L'],...]
```

or flattened

```
options = [ 'mass', '35kg', 'volume', '35L',...]
```

or an array of hash

```
options = [ {'mass': '35kg'}, {'volume': '35L'} ,...]
```

#### Permit method

The syntax in rails [is very particular and misleading](http://patshaughnessy.net/2014/6/16/a-rule-of-thumb-for-strong-parameters). In a nutshell

```
params.require(:product).permit(
  :name, 
  :active, 
  :main, 
  :category, 
  # Array of strings
  # => { options: ['mass', '35kg', 'amount', ...]}
  { options: [] },

  # Array of hashes 
  # => { options: [ {mass: '35kg'}, {amount: '35'}...] }
  { options: [:mass, :volume, :amount, :packing] }

  # Nested attributes 
  # => { options: {'mass': '35kg', amount: '35', ... } }
  options_attributes: [:mass, :volume, :price, :amount, :packing]
   )
```

The classic way is to use nested_attributes like this

```
class Product
  has_one :option # better not write the s to avoid pluralization headaches
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :option

class Option
  belongs_to :product
  field :mass, ...
```

In that case the declaration in the strong params should be (don't forget to use `= f.simple_fields_for :option do |ff|` without the `s`)

However, if you do not have the appropriate model (like in your case), the problem may come from the form builder object which doesn't behave properly (because the nested model doesn't exist). Instead try with just [fields_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) (without `f.simple_`)

```
fields_for :options do |ff|
```

Comment: The problem is that I have a lot of that is already working on the basis of seeds. In seeds options listed as an array, not a class. For this it is necessary to find a way out without using the class option.

Comment: The first solution didn't work ? with `:options => [],` ?

Comment: Yep.
@product[:options] still nill class

Comment: I updated my answer. But it would really help if you could post the full parameter string `puts params`